# REST api запросы соединенных сущностей в Symfony 3

Tags: symfony

Не могу передать данные при регистрации, в базу через запрос json в POSTMAN.

Сущность Пользователи

```
class oUser implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=4096)
 */
private $plainPassword;

/**
 * The below length depends on the "algorithm" you use for encoding
 * the password, but this works well with bcrypt.
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\oRole
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\oRole")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="roleid", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $role;
```

Сущность Роль.

class oRole
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
 */
private $code;
```

И сам метод POST передача данных в базу.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/user/")
 */
public function postUser(Request $request)
{
    $data = new oUser();
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $password = $request->get('password');
    $role = $request->get('role');
    if(empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($role))
    {
        return new View("NULL VALUES ARE NOT ALLOWED", Response::HTTP_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
    $data->setEmail($email);
    $data->setUsername($username);
    $data->setPassword($password);
    $data->setRole($role);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($data);
    $em->flush();
    return new View("User Added Successfully", Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Данные в postman.

```
{
"email": "gagg@mail.ru",
"username": "gaasd",
"password": "sdqwasdq",
"role": "1"
}
```

Ошибка.

> "message": "Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Entity\oUser::setRole() must be an instance of
>   AppBundle\Entity\oRole, string given, called in
>   D:\symfony\optovichok\src\AppBundle\Controller\RegisterRESTController.php
>   on line 66"